# Limiting results of Alfresco Get Activity Feed API

Tags: alfresco

I am currently using the Alfresco REST API call http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/activities/feed/user?format=json and it works fine.

However, it returns a list of all activities that the user has performed since he joins Alfresco. I have checked the official documentation, alfresco/services/index, and the wiki, but there seems to be no parameter I can pass into the script to limit the results returned by date.

Is there a way I can limit the results to activities performed in the last 7 days? The Share interface does this through the dashlet, so I'm wondering how I can do it from an external application.

Comment: Which version of Alfresco are you using? 4.x? 5.x? 3.x?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Much of the information you need can actually be found from Alfresco itself, if you know how to look! Sadly though, the answer is *no*

First off, head to `http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/index/all` (tweak as appropriate), and scroll about half way down until you find the URL of interest defined. Next, click the ID of that webscript, should be something like `https://cliq.quanticate.com/alfresco/service/script/org/alfresco/repository/activities/feed/userfeed.get`

That shows you all the well-known parameters available, the URL paths supported, response formats etc. As you'll see, there are no date filters available. We can also double check that, by looking at the line:

```
Implementation: class org.alfresco.repo.web.scripts.activities.feed.UserFeedRetrieverWebScript
```

You can [see the source code for that here](https://svn.alfresco.com/repos/alfresco-open-mirror/alfresco/HEAD/root/projects/remote-api/source/java/org/alfresco/repo/web/scripts/activities/feed/UserFeedRetrieverWebScript.java), and see there are no date filters

Finally, as this is used in the Activities dashlet, just load that up! Then check your Alfresco access logs, and you'll see that the URL fetched is like `"GET /alfresco/service/api/activities/feed/user?format=json HTTP/1.1"`. Alfresco Share itself fetches everything and filters it, so you'll need to do that

Answer (score 1):

1. Now you can limit result of http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/api/activities/feed/user?format=json

   ```
   activities.feed.max.size=200       # 200 - default value
   ```

   activityService bean configuration: https://github.com/lsbueno/alfresco/blob/master/root/projects/repository/config/alfresco/activities/activities-feed-context.xml
2. You can use the new REST API https://api-explorer.alfresco.com/api-explorer/#!/people/getActivities

   ```
   GET http://localhost:8080/alfresco/api/-default-/public/alfresco/versions/1/people/-me-/activities?maxItems=3&skipCount=2
   ```